# How to click dynamically created radio buttons by data?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
<form id="form">
<table id="VIPs" width="400">
<tbody>
<tr id="heading">
<tr>
<td>
<input id="VIP" type="radio" name="VIP" value="1" checked="true"/>
</td>
<td>Sylvester</td>
<td>Stallone</td>
<td>Male</td>
<td>Movie</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<td>Elvis</td>
<td>Presley</td>
<td>Male</td>
<td>Music</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<td>Marie</td>
<td>Curie</td>
<td>Female</td>
<td>Science</td>
```

From the above code snippet how can I click a radio button corresponding to a specific name using selenium java ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='VIP']")).click()
```

which will eventually clicks the radio button.